# Integrate Fourier Series and find sum

Tags: fourier-series

By integrating the Fourier series equation $$y(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{cos((2m+1)x)}{(2m+1)^2} $$

term by term from 0 to x, find the function $g(x)$ whose Fourier series is 
$$g(x) = \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{sin((2m+1)x)}{(2m+1)^3} $$

I don't understand how the negative sign in front of the series in the first equation turns positive, or how the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ disappears/ goes into the series somehow?

Comment: I think integrating $y(x)$ will give you a function equal to $x \pi/2 - g(x)$, and you can find $g(x)$ from the equality

Comment: It doesn't. But you can fiddle with the function you *do* get to change it into the one you want pretty easily.